# Receive data using Python sockets UDP IPV6 for a specific source address and port

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp, ipv6

im trying to implement a server client app with python using the sockets module (running on windows), this is the simplest way that ive found over the internet:

for server:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = ''
UDP_PORT = 42557

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
a = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print ("received message:", data)
    print("addr is:", addr)
    sock.close()
    break
```

for client :

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "::1"
UDP_PORT = 42557
MESSAGE = b"0000000EC4030004004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print ("message:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, # Internet
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.close()
```

ok this is working fine.

The thing is, i have a pcap file with several packages, if i reproduce that file i can see all the packages passing through the interface (ethernet card) using wire shark .

the question is, how do i get those packages using the socket module? ive tried like a bunch of ways and i cant see a thing (im a noob with sockets).

in the pcap file basically the info is the following:

Source Address: FD53:7CB8:0383:0002:0000:0000:0.0.0.105
Destination Address: FF14:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0.0.0.28
Source port: 42994
Destination port: 42512

with some random data in the payload. i.e: 0000000EC4030004004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the destination address configured on any interface?

Comment: What does it mean ' if i reproduce that file'

Comment: @branero79 he probably means to playback the PCAP file to re-transmit the packets that were previously captured in it.

Comment: @Joseph your code is using port 42557, but that example PCAP packet does not, so of course your sockets won't be able to see it. Same if the IPv6 addresses on the packet don't match the IPv6 addresses of your network interfaces. If you have a PCAP from another machine, you usually need to use [bittwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net) or similar tool to alter the PCAP packets to match the machine the PCAP will be played back on.

Comment: Hello @KlausD. is not configured.

Comment: Hello @branero79 i use a program to playback the pcap file as Remy commented.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, i just changed the port number and still im not able to see the packages, the ip address do not match the network interfaces addresses but wire shark is able to see the packages, im performing the playback of the pcap file on the same machine has the script.

Comment: @Joseph if the addresses in the pcap don’t match the addresses in the interfaces, the packets can’t be delivered to your script.

Comment: @Josef I am not sure how you can replay your pcap file with one tool and receive it with socket interface in the script. Is this what you want to do?  You send your packets/pcap with one tool(which tool?), you expect to receive them in your script(the script will receive only once and then break if I see correctly) You monitor the communication with Wireshark. Consider updating your post/title with more specific questions.

Comment: hello @branero79, the tool to replay the pcap file is called "Colasoft", i expect to receive them with the script to test the app that will process the data received, i thought that some how i could make something alike wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/rigtorp/udpreplay and it worked.
I used the loop-back interface so the IP address was not an issue and the send port and the receive port must be different.

My sequence was.

1. send a short text message from a client to the server and record it with Wireshark.
2. record with Wireshark the message I sent.
3. replay the recorded with udpreplay message and check if the server receives it.

I would first suggest:

1. Try to replay your message with a different tool. Initially, I tried with tcpreplay and it did not work.
2. Try to replay one message on the same PC with the loopback interface to be sure that your tool is working before you move to more complex pcap recorded on a different PC.

to try to reply to this simple message.

```
./udpreplay -i lo -l hello_from_client.pcapng
```

Server/Client example I found online

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
  
#define DST_PORT    8080 
#define SRC_PORT    8081
#define MAXLINE 1024 

#define IP      "127.0.0.1"
  
// Driver code 
int main() { 
    struct sockaddr_in addr, srcaddr;
    int sockfd;
    char message[] = "Hello, World!";
    char *hello = "Hello from clinet"; 

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    addr.sin_port = htons(DST_PORT);

    memset(&srcaddr, 0, sizeof(srcaddr));
    srcaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srcaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    srcaddr.sin_port = htons(SRC_PORT);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &srcaddr, sizeof(srcaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr,  
            sizeof(addr)); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

    int n, len;
    char buffer[256];
          
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,  
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer); 
  
    close(sockfd); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Server:

```
// Server side implementation of UDP client-server model 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
  
#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 
  
// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
      
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
      
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 
      
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
      
    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,  
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
      
    int len, n; 
  
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);  //len is value/resuslt 
  
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,  
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),  
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
            len); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");  
      
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @branero79 , I'll try that and let you as soon as I do it.